Strange behavior of Polygon with a hole
I observed a strange behavior using Polygon with Graphics3D in MMA14.1.
Here is my example.
    polygon = {{-0.4, 1.7, 0.}, {-0.8, 1.7, 0.}, {-1.2, 1.8, 0.}, {-1.4, 
    1.9, 0.}, {-1.5, 2., 0.}, {-1.5, -0.5, 0.}, {1, -0.5, 0.}, {1, 
    1.8, 0.}};
    hole = {{0., 0., 0}, {0.5, 0., 0.}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.}, {0., 0.5, 0.}};
    Graphics3D[Polygon[polygon -> hole], Axes -> True]

Its result is an unfilled 3D polygon on the XY-plane.

However, by slightly changing the first coordinate, for example ( {-0.4, 1.7, 0.} -> {-0.4, 1.8, 0.} ), it works as expected.

Could someone please explain this situation?
According to the suggestion from user64494
Graphics3D[
 Polygon[Join @@ (Append[#, #[[1]]] & /@ {polygon, Reverse[hole]})]]



As Wiki says "Polygons with holes can be dissected into multiple polygons by adding new edges, so they are not frequently needed".

Edit
For version 14.1.0, we can use DiscreteRegioin+RegionPlot3D ( but version 14.0.0 does not work)
(* Version 14.1.0  *)
poly = Polygon[polygon -> hole]
RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@poly, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive@{Red, Thickness[.01]}]


Original
The 2D case work , it seems be a bug.
reg2d = Polygon[polygon[[;; , {1, 2}]] -> hole[[;; , {1, 2}]]];
(* reg2d = BoundaryMeshRegion[
  Join[polygon[[;; , {1, 2}]], 
   hole[[;; , {1, 2}]]], {Line[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1}], 
   Line[{9, 10, 11, 12, 9}]}] *)
Graphics[reg2d, Axes -> True, TicksStyle -> Cyan]


reg3d = RegionProduct[reg2d, Point[{0.}]];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], reg3d}]



Oh, is that so?
Could you please report this to Wolfram?

Please see this question here

The behaviour is explained in the documentation for RenderingOptions:

Nearly coplanar polygons may be rendered inconsistently by default rendering methods.

You can change the rendering method to get the correct result:
polygon = {{-0.4, 1.7, 0.}, {-0.8, 1.7, 0.}, {-1.2, 1.8, 0.}, {-1.4, 1.9, 0.}, 
           {-1.5, 2., 0.}, {-1.5, -0.5, 0.}, {1, -0.5, 0.}, {1, 1.8, 0.}};
hole = {{0., 0., 0}, {0.5, 0., 0.}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.}, {0., 0.5, 0.}};
p1 = Polygon[polygon -> hole]

Style[Graphics3D[p1], RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingMethod" -> "BSPTree"}]



OP points are NOT "nearly coplanar". They are coplanar exactly. You can replace the coordinates with exact values by applying Rationalize and the bug still persist.

@azerbajdzan, generally, there is no such thing as exact when doing numerical computations. There are various types of numerical errors, which can lead to wrong results. Obviously, I don't have a proof that this is the real reason here, just my hunch. Note that Rationalize has absolutely no effect here, because rendering is not done with exact arithmetics.

The point is that the error is not on the user's side as the user provided input in the most accurate form. The error is on the side of the software. Anyway your answer is useful as a workaround.

I thank you both for very thought-provoking discussions.
